# cannot find the file specified

Tags: java

can not get the file path of uploadedFile. my code is

```
String s=FilenameUtils.getFullPath(uploadedFile.getName());
```

output value of s=""

how can i get the full path of the specified file?

Comment: What is the type of "uploadedFile"? There is a lot of missing context here. Are you using a framework?

Comment: Can you post your full source code? It's nearly impossible to tell what's wrong from this snippet.

Comment: Actually I have use JSF framework..and the type of file is UploadeFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `uploadedFile` is referring to a file uploaded from a web browser to your web server, then you will be unable to get its full path.  If a browser transmitted the full path of uploaded files to a web server, that information could be used maliciously.  You'll have to make do with the file name.

Comment: Then how can i get the path of the uploaded file

Comment: You don't need the path of the file; it's not stored on your file system yet.  If you want it stored on your file system, you must retrieve its contents and save them to disk.  Or perhaps you don't need to store it on your FS at all.  It depends on what you're trying to do with the file.

Comment: i am trying to send the file as am attachment with email.